# Разные размеры Label (его содержимого)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Здравствуйте. Как в Xcode принято решать следующую проблему? 
Есть у меня на экране лейбл, который в стандартном положении выглядит так, как надо, от края до края.

[image: Стандартное положение]

А вот в горизонтальном уже не так как надо. Длина текста остается той же (сам лейбл растягивается автосайзом), что и логично.

[image: Горизонтальное положение]

Мне нужно, чтобы в гор.положении текст также был от края до края, то есть выходит стояло больше точек? Думаю, размер шрифта менять неверное решение, ибо пропорционально он может больше в высоту увеличиваться, нежели в длину, да и для каждого девайса с разными экранами так подбирать устанешь.

Так должно быть
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Текст задан программно и таких лейблов много, друг за другом стоят в виде таблицы.

Что обычно делают в таких ситуациях? Программирую на Objective-C

Comment: Можно уточнить, вам точно нужны точки? Если нет, вам поможет Auto Layout https://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1.
Если нужны точки, то вам придется их добавить программно.

Comment: @ivan-kramarchuk да, точно точки. Я же написал, что сам лейбл размеры меняет

Comment: Может все же лучше сделать 2 label по краям и пунктирную линию между ними?

Comment: @Bandicoot Как Вы данный UILabel создаёте? Как пытаетесь его размер и позицию поменять?

Comment: @roman-podymov Создаю в IB. Autosize настроил тоже через IB

Answer (score 0):

Всё можно решить и без Auto Layout. Все необходимые размеры строк можно рассчитать самому, и в дальнейшем использовать их в коде. Надеюсь, у Вас есть свойство, которое хранит ссылку на используемый Вами `UILabel` (у меня в коде оно называется `label`).  Добавьте следующие свойства в класс Вашего `UIViewController`:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSString* beginString;
@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSString* endString;
@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSString* dotString;

@property (nonatomic, readonly) CGFloat widthOfBeginString;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CGFloat widthOfEndString;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CGFloat widthOfOneDotString;
```

И проинициализируйте их (например, в `viewDidLoad`):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    _beginString = @"Кот";
    _endString = @"Мышь";
    _dotString = @".";

    _widthOfBeginString = [self widthOfString:_beginString limitedByHeight:self.label.frame.size.height font:self.label.font];
    _widthOfEndString = [self widthOfString:_endString limitedByHeight:self.label.frame.size.height font:self.label.font];
    _widthOfOneDotString = [self widthOfString:_dotString limitedByHeight:self.label.frame.size.height font:self.label.font];
}
```

Здесь я использую вспомогательную функцию для расчёта ширины строки:

```
-(CGFloat)widthOfString:(NSString*)str limitedByHeight:(CGFloat)height font:(UIFont*)font {

    CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(CGFLOAT_MAX, height);
    CGRect boundingRect = [str boundingRectWithSize:constraintSize
                                            options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                         attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: font}
                                            context:nil];
    return boundingRect.size.width;
}
```

Теперь нам надо менять текст Вашего `UILabel`, основываясь на ширине отображаемой области. Я предлагаю сделать это в `viewWillLayoutSubviews`:

```
-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {

    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
    _label.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, self.view.frame.size.height/2.0, self.view.frame.size.width, _label.frame.size.height);
    _label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", _beginString, [@"" stringByPaddingToLength:[self dotsCountForWidth:self.view.frame.size.width - _widthOfBeginString - _widthOfEndString] withString:_dotString startingAtIndex:0], _endString];
}
```

Здесь я использовал ещё одну дополнительную функцию для расчёта необходимого количества точек для заполнения строки:

```
-(NSUInteger)dotsCountForWidth:(CGFloat)width {

    return floorf(width/_widthOfOneDotString);
}
```

Comment: Попробую сделать все как у вас, отпишусь. Спасибо

Comment: @Bandicoot До сих пор жду, пока отпишитесь.